# php simple loop incrementing char

Tags: php, char

while doing a very simple check I've wrote

```
$char = 'a';
while ( $char < "z" ) {
    echo $char++ . ' ';
}
```

and as expected the output was `a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y`. then I changed the condition to `<=` like

```
$char = 'a';
while ( $char <= "z" ) {
    echo $char++ . ' ';
}
```

I expected `a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z` **But** the real output was

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z aa ab ac ad ae af ag ah ai aj ak al am an ao ap aq ar as at au av aw ax ay az ba bb bc bd be bf bg bh bi bj bk bl bm bn bo bp bq br bs bt bu bv bw bx by bz ca cb cc cd ce cf cg ch ci cj ck cl cm cn co cp cq cr cs ct cu cv cw cx cy cz da db dc dd de df dg dh di dj dk dl dm dn do dp dq dr ds dt du dv dw dx dy dz ea eb ec ed ee ef eg eh ei ej ek el em en eo ep eq er es et eu ev ew ex ey ez fa fb fc fd fe ff fg fh fi fj fk fl fm fn fo fp fq fr fs ft fu fv fw fx fy fz ga gb gc gd ge gf gg gh gi gj gk gl gm gn go gp gq gr gs gt gu gv gw gx gy gz ha hb hc hd he hf hg hh hi hj hk hl hm hn ho hp hq hr hs ht hu hv hw hx hy hz ia ib ic id ie if ig ih ii ij ik il im in io ip iq ir is it iu iv iw ix iy iz ja jb jc jd je jf jg jh ji jj jk jl jm jn jo jp jq jr js jt ju jv jw jx jy jz ka kb kc kd ke kf kg kh ki kj kk kl km kn ko kp kq kr ks kt ku kv kw kx ky kz la lb lc ld le lf lg lh li lj lk ll lm ln lo lp lq lr ls lt lu lv lw lx ly lz ma mb mc md me mf mg mh mi mj mk ml mm mn mo mp mq mr ms mt mu mv mw mx my mz na nb nc nd ne nf ng nh ni nj nk nl nm nn no np nq nr ns nt nu nv nw nx ny nz oa ob oc od oe of og oh oi oj ok ol om on oo op oq or os ot ou ov ow ox oy oz pa pb pc pd pe pf pg ph pi pj pk pl pm pn po pp pq pr ps pt pu pv pw px py pz qa qb qc qd qe qf qg qh qi qj qk ql qm qn qo qp qq qr qs qt qu qv qw qx qy qz ra rb rc rd re rf rg rh ri rj rk rl rm rn ro rp rq rr rs rt ru rv rw rx ry rz sa sb sc sd se sf sg sh si sj sk sl sm sn so sp sq sr ss st su sv sw sx sy sz ta tb tc td te tf tg th ti tj tk tl tm tn to tp tq tr ts tt tu tv tw tx ty tz ua ub uc ud ue uf ug uh ui uj uk ul um un uo up uq ur us ut uu uv uw ux uy uz va vb vc vd ve vf vg vh vi vj vk vl vm vn vo vp vq vr vs vt vu vv vw vx vy vz wa wb wc wd we wf wg wh wi wj wk wl wm wn wo wp wq wr ws wt wu wv ww wx wy wz xa xb xc xd xe xf xg xh xi xj xk xl xm xn xo xp xq xr xs xt xu xv xw xx xy xz ya yb yc yd ye yf yg yh yi yj yk yl ym yn yo yp yq yr ys yt yu yv yw yx yy yz
```

so why exactly the output wasn't what I've expected? I'm using `PHP 7.0.8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little know feature of PHP.

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a = 'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the original string is unchanged.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

The incrementing operator on strings is an exception. It is from a different numeral system than most other operators. It is easier to describe this problem on digits. You have `1`. It can be interpreted as `0001` or `1000`. These are two different numbers. The interpretation depends on the used operator.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the increment operator on a string. It doesn't work like you think it does.

```
$str = 'z';
var_dump(++$str)
```

Output:

```
aa
```

If you're looking to loop over each letter, `range()` works nicely:

```
foreach (range('a', 'z') as $letter) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: I know it's a perl style increment in php not C style -like I've used to deal with- but I assumed that `aa` is greater than `z` so the condition `$char <= "z"` should terminate the loop

Comment: try `var_dump('aa' > 'z');`

Comment: I.e., when using the comparison operators on two strings that are not numerical, it compares them alphabetically.

Comment: thanks for help @Alex the `var_dump` showed some interesting output. like `aa` it less than `z`! I've to study php variables again I think